# Flat lower back and pain

Tags: back-pain, lower-back, lower-body-strength, spine

I have pain in the lower part of my back. When I go to the gym I try to not overload that part of my body. I just bought a foam roller to stretch out my back before and after my workout.

I also seem to have a 'flat lower back' when I bend over (red line), I can't bend any further because I hurst to bad otherwise (in the lower back):

[image]

What do you guys suggest I should do, keep stretching? See a doctor

Comment: Seeking answers for pain on this site is never a good idea.  You've answered your own question: by all means seek the advice of a medical professional.

Comment: By hurt  do you mean actually "hurt", or is it more of a sore feeling? If it is the former, a sports therapist will help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest getting yourself checked. Never guess or assume anything when it comes to pain. The cause would be anything, but with proper attention at the right time, any issue can be fixed. Don't deal with the pain, just get diagnosed by a doctor and eliminate it.